Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated Tailwind
After run npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./src/output.css --watch for TailwindCss, this is what i see:

Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
npx update-browserslist-db@latest
Why you should do it regularly: https://github.com/browserslist/update-db#readme

Then i run npx update-browserslist-db@latest, and this is my result:


Even after updating browserlist the problem persists, right? Are you on WSL?
